# Defining TkInter StringVars in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My program iterates through a list of values and creates a new frame with relevant information. I want to add a button to refresh the values in just one of the frames. The following image is a mockup of what I'm trying to achieve, where the "reload" button grabs new data for just one printer.[image: Mockup]

I'm running into an issue where only the last values get updated. The following code is an approximation of what I was trying:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def buttonupdate(x):
    return int(x.get())+1

root=tk.Tk()

values=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
stringVarList=[]

for i,item in enumerate(values):
    newStringVar=tk.StringVar()
    newStringVar.set(item)
    stringVarList.append(newStringVar)

    valueLabel=tk.Label(root, textvariable=stringVarList[i])
    valueLabel.grid(row=0,column=i)

    button=tk.Button(root, text="+1", command=lambda:stringVarList[i].set(buttonupdate(stringVarList[i])))
    button.grid(row=1, column=i)

root.mainloop()
```

With this code, only the last value gets updated, no matter which button I press.

[image]

What can I try instead? Thank you.

Comment: The problem isn't with the StringVars themselves: the Button's `command=` lambda is choosing one of the StringVars based on the variable `i` - which has taken on its final loop value by the time any of the Buttons could possibly be clicked.  One solution is to *capture* the value of `i` at the moment when the lambda was defined - `lambda i=i: ...`

Comment: @jasonharper that was exactly it. Thank you!